# How to add library in keil for stm32?

Tags: embedded, stm32, developer-tools, keil, firmware

I am Working on STM32 controller, need to add some other downloaded library from the ST's website.
I need to add the downloaded library of the X cube Crypto Graph in keil IDE.
So if any one know about it please let me know that how do I do it.

Comment: add the C files to the project. If it is a compiled library Keil does not support gcc object or library formats.

Comment: okay, It will great of your if you can guide me steps for do these in keil - IDE.

Comment: If it is `.lib` file then it can be added simply, there is an option on GUI (I do not remember exactly where it is) to add the library in the project. But if it is `.c` and `.h` files, then you need to add files in the project and also need to include path in the project.